# Understanding replacement using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all trailing and leading dashes (`-`) and replace any repeating dashes with one dash otherwise in JavaScript. I've developed a regex to do it:

```
"----asdas----asd-as------q---".replace(/^-+()|()-+$|(-)+/g,'$3')
```

And it works:

```
asdas-asd-as-q
```

But I don't understand the `$3` part (obtained through desperate experiment). Why not `$1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use this without any capturing groups:

```
"----asdas----asd-as------q---".replace(/^-+|-+$|-+(?=-)/g, '');
//=> "asdas-asd-as-q"
```

Here `-+(?=-)` is a **positive lookahead** that makes sure to match 1 or more hyphens except the last `-` in the match.

Comment: +1, but probably a good idea to briefly explain that lookahead ;)

Comment: Thanks, I added a brief explanation to my answer.

Comment: +1 for much better solution than mine, but doesn't exactly answer my question

Comment: @JakubFedyczak: To answer your question directly, since you had 2 empty captured groups your code was using `$3` which was last captured group here `(-)+`. But honestly that implementation looks buggy that's why I suggested an improvement.

Comment: @JakubFedyczak By itself your question is kind of off-topic for StackOverflow, since any basic documentation will tell you what `$3` means and from that you can tell why you need that number. That's why several answers here (including my own) are suggesting better ways to do it, as well as simply explaining the reason.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I may have stated my question better. Real source of my confusion was why $3 becomes an empty string in first two alternatives and not in third one. I think I now get it.

Answer (score 3):

Because there are 3 capturing groups. (two *redundant* empty ones and `(-)`). `$3` replaced with the string that matched the third group.

If you remove the first two empty capturing groups, you can use `$1`.

```
"----asdas----asd-as------q---".replace(/^-+|-+$|(-)+/g, '$1')
// => "asdas-asd-as-q"
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers say, `$3` indicates the third captured subpattern, ie. third set of parentheses.

Personally, however, I would see that as two operations, and do it as such:

1. Trim leading and trailing `-`s
2. Condense duplicate `-`s

Like so:

```
"----asdas----asd-as------q---".replace(/^-+|-+$/g,"").replace(/--+/g,"-");
```

This kind of concept may mean more code, but I believe it makes it much easier to read and understand what's going on here, because you're doing one thing at a time instead of trying to do everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

$ are the replacement groups being formed.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/25

On the right side you can see the groups being generated by ().

Replace and see.$1 is blank in your case.